# Close MapQuest AnnotationView when clicking outside

Tags: android, mapquest

In Android, I have a MapQuest `MapView`.  The `MapView` has a `DefaultItemizedOverlay` with an `OverlayItem` that, when clicked, displays an `AnnotationView`.  This is basically what MapQuest demonstrates in the overlays section of their [Getting Started](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api/documentation#overlays) guide.

That works just fine but what a few people have noticed is that there is no way to close the annotation.  The user can click on another `OverlayItem` to display its annotation instead, but there's no way to hide one without opening another.  I could add a button to the annotation to close it but I would prefer to have it close when the user taps outside the annotation.  Is there a convenient way to do so?

The overlay already has an `OverlayTapListener` that displays the annotation.  I was looking at modifying its logic but I found that it only gets called when an overlay item is tapped, not when the user taps elsewhere.  Short of overriding the overlay's `onTouchEvent()` method and replicating its logic with small changes, does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled a lot with the same issue, and finally I found a workaround!

```
myMapView.addMapViewEventListener(new MapView.MapViewEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void moveStart(MapView mapView) { }
    @Override
    public void move(MapView mapView) { }
    @Override
    public void moveEnd(MapView mapView) { }
    @Override
    public void touch(MapView mapView) {
        annotation.hide();
    }
    @Override
    public void longTouch(MapView mapView) { }
    @Override
    public void zoomStart(MapView mapView) { }
    @Override
    public void zoomEnd(MapView mapView) { }
    @Override
    public void mapLoaded(MapView mapView) { }
});
```

It basically closes the annotation if clicked anywhere but markers on the map.

Hope it helps someone else who struggles to use the free MapQuest API.